# How should I enter organizational units into my contacts?

Tags: contacts

The (Android) contacts system is modeled to contain *individual people*'s contact info: There's a name, a last name, an organization/company the person is in, address etc.

However, we also need to keep the contact information for organizations, or departments/units within organization. For example: The customer support line of a branch of company.

What's the right way to have this information in your contacts?

One thing you can do is  just divide the information somehow between a pseudo-name and the overall company info. This is already crooked, semantically, since you'll have a name that's not a name; but its even more untenable, because the company name is critical, while not being displayed or being shown in small print when a call is incoming or when browsing the contacts.

What I actually do is shove everything into the name somehow, *and* use the most recognizable company name to start my "name".

Are there other options I'm missing?